# I can't cypher an avro message using jpgpj

Tags: scala, pgp

I am trying to encrypt avro messages with schema using jpgpj library and it gives me an exception when encrypting:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: no suitable signing key found
    at org.c02e.jpgpj.Encryptor.sign(Encryptor.java:982)
    at org.c02e.jpgpj.Encryptor.prepareCiphertextOutputStream(Encryptor.java:773)
    at org.c02e.jpgpj.Encryptor.encrypt(Encryptor.java:691)
    at org.c02e.jpgpj.Encryptor.encrypt(Encryptor.java:662)
    at avro.EncryptPayload$.main(EncryptPayload.scala:40)
    at avro.EncryptPayload.main(EncryptPayload.scala)
```

I generate the pair of keys using these commands:

```
gpg --gen-key

gpg --armor --output public-key.gpg --export myemail@gmail.com
```

Then, I copied public-key.gpg file to src/main/resources in a project with this [code](https://gist.github.com/alonsoir/acfff23335eae53b5a7cd8f80171e951) and the exception happens. The exception is clear, I can see it in sources.
It is not a problem about a file not found, it is a problem that says that the public key cannot be used as a key to sign the message, and it confuses me. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem vanished when I changed this line:

```
    encryptor.setSigningAlgorithm(HashingAlgorithm.SHA256)
```

to this line:

```
    encryptor.setSigningAlgorithm(HashingAlgorithm.Unsigned)
```

EDIT

I share the [gist](https://gist.github.com/alonsoir/acfff23335eae53b5a7cd8f80171e951) with the code